# CXF request response logging using log4j: debug

Tags: debugging, log4j, weblogic, cxf

I am trying to enable logging for cxf framework in weblogic application server along with log4j.

I have placed cxf.xml in domain home and have modified setdomainenv to add cxf.xml entry -Dcxf.config.file.url=cxf.xml. 
I am setting System.setProperty("org.apache.cxf.Logger", "org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger") before making a webservice call and i have tried configuring all 3 types of configuration specified in http://cxf.apache.org/docs/configuration.html. But nothing seems to work.

I even tried creating `org.apache.cxf.Logger` file containing  value `org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger`.

my `log4j.properties`
    log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE
    log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf=DEBUG
    log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
    log4j.appender.FILE.File=<>/logFile.log
    log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n

`CXF version: 2.7.5`

Please suggest if there is change required for me to log both request and response xml?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your org.apache.cxf.Logger file is under META-INF/cxf.  Inspect your war to make sure.

Also, assuming you are defining your services using jaxws, make sure you're defining loggers under the jaxws:inInterceptor and jaxws:outInterceptor

```
<jaxws:client id="..." serviceClass="..." address="..." >
  <jaxws:outInterceptors>
    <ref bean="logOut" />
  </jaxws:outInterceptors>
  <jaxws:inInterceptors>
    <ref bean="logIn"/>
  </jaxws:inInterceptors>
</jaxws:client> 

<bean class='org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor' id='logIn'/>

<bean class='org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor' id='logOut'/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but this does not help me. I have made sure that org.apache.cxf.Logger file present after building the war. But when that didnt work i moved to domain home by settting -Dcxf.config.file.url=cxf.xml (is there way to verify that this file is loaded).

And i am not using jaxws. I making the webservice calls from Port class generated when i run wsdl2java in mvn.